# Check input item according defined index. Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I have an input element which is of type `radio` and I want set checked this according defined index. I tried `index` and `indexOf` functions but I received "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" error. Which function should I use ?

Code sample =>

```
$("input:radio[name='phase_list']").indexOf(index).attr("checked", true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `eq()` selector instead . also for checking checkbox in jquery 1.6+ versions, use `prop('checked', true)`:

```
 $("input:radio[name='phase_list']").eq(index).prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) as shown :-

```
$("input:radio[name='phase_list']").get(index).checked = true;
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6507w2z0/1/)

Comment: are you sure this code is work ? I tried and I got same error

Comment: @Eren..little change ... see updated answer..the problem was .get() gives dom element with specified index after that we have to use javascript syntax not jquery syntax.